# How is the measurement light frequency shifted with respect to the reference light frequency by some carrier frequency in practice?

Tags: frequency, modulation, optics, photonics

I've been studying heterodyning in interferometry. My understanding is that heterodyning is achieved by shifting the measurement light frequency with respect
to the reference light frequency by some carrier frequency. However, it isn't clear to me how this is actually done in practice/applications. I've read through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodyne) Wikipedia article on heterodyning, but it still isn't clear to me. So how is the measurement light frequency shifted with respect
to the reference light frequency by some carrier frequency in practice/application?

Comment: One obvious way to do it is via Doppler shift (just move a mirror).  Another is, an acousto optical modulator:  https://www.rp-photonics.com/acousto_optic_modulators.html

Comment: with a non-linear device for the mixer, and light of a different frequency as the LO. To get an IF in the detectable microwave region, the LO needs to be very close to the incoming signal frequency.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_heterodyne_detection

Comment: @user1850479 So let's say I'm using a heterodyne interferometer to measure something that oscillates with frequency \$ f \$. It's the "measurement light" in question that we shine on the oscillating 'thing', and whose frequency then shifts depending on the oscillations of the 'thing', right? So what part does the AOM then play in this?

Comment: @ThePointer The frequency shift is caused by the AOM and can be applied to either arm (sample or reference).  Usually the object itself is assumed to impart no or at least small (relative to the AOM) frequency shift.  If it isn't then demodulating the signal will be hard due to it crossing zero frequency.

Comment: @user1850479 Hmm, so what is the relationship between the AOM, the object being measured by the heterodyne interferometer, and my question? (You seem to be familiar with these parts, so I'm just trying to better understand this.)

Comment: See this figure for the case of a moving or vibrating object:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer#/media/File:LDV_Schematic.png  Note that AOM is another term for Bragg cell.

Comment: @user1850479 I've seen that diagram, but I'm interested in an explanation within the context of this question.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking then.  Edit your question to reflect whatever it is you are hoping to learn.

Comment: @user1850479 My question is as follows: how is the measurement light frequency shifted with respect to the reference light frequency by some carrier frequency in practice? You commented that AOMs are used for this purpose. So I'm asking what the relationship is between the AOM, the oscillating 'thing' being measured by the heterodyne interferometer, and my question. I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand how all of these elements are related in this context, so I'm just trying to understand/learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126083/discussion-between-user1850479-and-the-pointer).

Comment: Here's an ad of commercial products https://www.hcphotonics.com/ppln-mixers The ad is full of cryptic terminology. One example: PPLN is one technique to reduce the dependence of signal propagation velocity on frequency to make wanted quantum interactions probable enough in reasonable short paths of nonlinear optical material. I'm afraid that you cannot get comprehensive answers here because most of us are practical electricians. Photonics and nonlinear opticks are outside of our comfort zone.

Comment: I *am* asking about the practical electronics. What you’re describing here is not what I am interested in. I just saw an answer here hours ago that seemed to be what I was looking for; but, unfortunately, I have no idea what happened to that answer (deleted?).

Comment: I noticed when it was under construction it repeated things that were already said maybe with finer words in comments which were already judged useless. Thus I removed it. It had only some drawings more than the comments. I can restore it if needed. BTW the ad of off the shelf components should be considered practical for those who try to construct some optical signal processing or terabit data transmission.

Comment: @user287001 oh, I was only able to read the very first part, but it looked promising. I really am just interested in the practical electronics involved in making this work (that is, *how* it works). I don’t see any comment addressing my question in a direct and explained way, so I’m not really sure what comment(s) you’re referring to.

Comment: Also look up an older method, "serrodyne," where a mirror or fiber is physically moved with a sawtooth-shaped drive signal.  This creates a constant frequency-shift  ...if we ignore the brief "flyback" portion of the sawtooth timing.  Combine it with the original light, and each different wavelength will have a different beat-signal up in the MHz.  The opto spectrum becomes a radio spectrum with thousands of channels.

Comment: @wbeaty Thanks for the comment. I have some questions, if you don't mind: 1. Does this method work If the 'thing' that I'm measuring vibrates with a frequency of 1 MHz? The research papers I read had it in the low kHz range. 2. Is it cheaper than using an AOM (do you happen to know approximately how much?)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some helpful clarification, here's a more complete answer.

First, to the direction question: how is the light shifted in a heterodyne detection system for a [laser Doppler interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer)?" They typically use a Bragg cell (AOM, or acoustic optical modulator). A Bragg cell basically uses phase modulation as a way to cause a tiny shift in the frequency of light, just small enough for detection in the 10s of kHz range. It's a non-linear mixing process in the material selected at a specific frequency. These things can be expensive, though (thousands to 10's of thousands of dollars). The way they work is that the AOM material itself is non-linear (the index of refraction changes with optical intensity), so the trick is to set it up in a way such that the beam of light and the non-linear generated beam of light are "phase matched," that is, the AOM steers the generated beam a little bit such that the generated wave wavefronts line up over each other as they travel through the AOM material. You can then basically phase modulate the light, which is the same thing as a Doppler shift - thus shifting the frequency of the light.

The question is basically "how does a [laser Doppler interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer) measure a vibrating thing in practice for homodyne detection?" There are two parts to consider, the physical set up and the physics/signal processing.

First, the physical equipment set up. The set up would be to use a single laser in to a beamsplitter (I just searched amazon a found a bunch for cheap, a 50:50 laser beamsplitter would work - or check edmund optics or thorlabs for scientific grade products). You now have two beams. Using mirrors, shine one through the Bragg cell (or skip the Bragg cell for homodyne) then on to your object, reflect off of the object, and steer it to the photodiode. The other beam goes to the photodiode. Ideally, you'd want the intensity of both beams to be about the same, so you might use something other than a 50:50 beamsplitter or you might use a neutral density filter (i.e., something that attenuates the light intensity) on the brighter arm - or just go with them not being balanced. Also, it's better if you can line up those too beams on top of each other again (e.g., "co-linear") by combining the two beams together in another beamsplitter, but it will still work even if you don't do that (just not as well).

Now that you have both beams on your photodiode, what do you get as a signal? This is where the physics comes in. On the detector you are adding two electric fields together, and the intensity detected is the square of that interference:

$$ I(t) \propto [ E_r\cos(2\pi (\nu+\Delta \nu) t + \phi (t)) + E_0\cos(2\pi \nu t)]^2$$

Where \$\nu\$ is the optical frequency of the laser, \$\Delta \nu\$ is the frequency shift from the Bragg cell (which is zero if you don't use it), \$\phi(t)\$ is the extra phase that's added because of the vibrating thing that it's reflecting off of, \$E_r\$ is the amplitude of the E-field from the reflected object, and \$E_0\$ is the amplitude of the E-field from the unperturbed light coming from the beamsplitter.

Multiplying this out:

$$ I(t) \propto E_r^2\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cos(2\pi (2\nu+2\Delta\nu) t + 2\phi (t))\right) \\ + E_0^2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \cos(2\pi (2\nu) t)\right)\\ + 2E_rE_0 \cos(2\pi (\nu+ \Delta \nu) t +\phi (t))\cos(2\pi \nu t) $$

looking at that last term:

$$ \cos(2\pi (\nu+\Delta\nu) t +\phi (t))\cos(2\pi \nu t)= \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(2\pi \Delta \nu+\phi (t))+\cos(2\pi (2\nu+\Delta\nu) t+\phi(t))\right) $$

And remembering that \$\phi(t)\$ is the thing you actually care about since \$\phi(t) = x(t)\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} +\phi_0 \$ where \$x(t)\$ is the displacement of the vibrating thing and \$\phi_0\$ is some almost random offset based on the path length difference between the two arms. So by filtering out the DC components and the optical components (\$ \ge \nu\$), assuming your vibrations are much slower than the optical frequency, you get:

$$I(t) \propto \cos(2\pi\Delta\nu t+ \phi (t) )$$

Which gets you access to what you originally wanted: something that's only a function of \$\phi(t)\$ and it's modulated at the \$\Delta \nu\$ frequency- all the optical stuff is removed. Since your thing is already vibrating at 10 MHz, you could consider just doing homodyne too, make \$\Delta \nu=0\$.

So you do the normal phase detection systems on the intensity signal. For example, yoi can mix it with a local oscillator at \$\Delta\nu\$ to get out \$\phi(t)\$.

Comment: The refractive index in an AOM changes with acoustic intensity, rather than optical intensity. That's the core idea, you can frequency shift a light wave by moving a sound wave through it. They also typically operate in the 20-1000 MHz range.

Comment: @user1850479 I've got a question, if you don't mind. You said that AOMs typically operate in the 20-1000 MHz range. If the 'thing' I'm measuring with the LDV is vibrating with a frequency of 1 MHz, does this mean that an AOM is unsuitable for my purpose (that is, is an AOM unsuitable for building such an LDV)?

Comment: @ThePointer AOMs are suitable for building laser doppler interferometers.

Comment: @user1850479 As KD9PDP said, AOMs are quite expensive. If I want to build an LDV that only measures an object vibrating at 1 MHz, rather than the general-purpose commercial LDVs that one can buy, is there a cheap way to do the frequency shifting? Since you're an optical engineer, what do you think @KD9PDP?

Comment: @ThePointer Second hand AOMs often go for tens of dollars on Ebay.  If that is too much, not all interferometers use them, and since your frequency of interest is relatively high you might not get that much benefit from one compared to audio frequencies.  You'd have to work out if that cost savings is practical/justified for your specific problem.

Comment: @user1850479 I’m thinking more for mass-production, rather than a one-time lab build. I can get one of these second-hand 40 MHz AOMs from eBay for around 200 USD, but if I want to mass produce a device at an economical price point, I’m guessing I’d have to pay over 500 USD for the commercial AOM alone (even if I design my own RF driver). Can you please elaborate on why you think I wouldn’t need an AOM for measuring a 1 MHz frequency? From what I’ve read, the AOM is a necessary part of the heterodyne interferometer so that it can know the *direction* of displacement of the object, right?

Comment: @ThePointer  Use the 1 MHz vibration to generate the frequency shift.  The AOM is the more common approach though.

Comment: @user1850479 Hmm, what do you mean by "use the 1 MHz vibration to generate the frequency shift"? Is there a paper you could link me to?

Comment: @ThePointer Textbook might be a better place to start.

Comment: @user1850479 I am indeed already studying through textbooks. But what exactly am I misunderstanding / should I be looking at?

Comment: @ThePointer This is a Michelson interferometer, so if you aren't sure how those work, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: @user1850479 My interpretation of everything I've read is that, for heterodyne interferometry, an AOM/EOM (or some other kind of modulator) needs to be used. Perhaps I misunderstood what I need to do to measure my 1 MHz vibration. I'd appreciate elaboration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126198/discussion-between-user1850479-and-the-pointer).

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

> My understanding is that heterodyning is achieved by shifting the measurement light frequency with respect to the reference light frequency by some carrier frequency.

I guess you have imagined the next frequency shifting scenario:

[image]

It's taken from systems which operate at microwaves or lower frequencies. It could in theory also work with light or infrared if we had working components for it and just those components are the thing you asked. The theoretical mixer is a multiplier or at least a controlled switch where one momentary signal voltage affects how much the other signal is attenuated or amplified. Numerous mixing circuits are known and work well in radio frequencies.

Also  light mixer is possible. Especially widely used one is a photodiode or other light intensity to voltage (or current) converter.

Unfortunately it can be used only to extract the frequency difference mixing result. If it gets simultaneously 2 light beams which have nearly or exactly the same frequency it generates a voltage which has some DC and the difference of the light beam frequencies. The frequencies must be so close each other that the difference is in the range possible for electronic circuits (=DC to microwave)

If you want to generate for ex. visible light as the sum frequency of 2 infrared beams you can inject the beams to the same piece of nonlinear optical material like lithium niobate.  The sum frequency mixing result really appears, but the conversion efficiency is below all acceptable  if nothing is done to satisfy quantum conservation laws (energy, momentum).

Those laws are satisfied well enough in radio frequency circuits without any special effort, but in optical frequencies one must use some special structures to remove the frequency dependency of the propagation velocity. Here are some commercial mixers which have the problem solved: https://www.hcphotonics.com/ppln-mixers

Another problem is the local oscillator. Ordinary easily available lasers have somehow randomly drifting phase angle and the polarization (=the direction of the wave electric field)  Stable enough "pure sinewave" local oscillator with constant polarization is a must for highest quality mixing which does not insert any randomness to the signal, only changes its frequency. How scientists have constructed best quality local oscillators beyond ordinary lasers is out of the scope of this answer.

As already said, the difference of frequencies can be formed easily with a photodiode or other light intensity to voltage (or current) converter if the difference is in the possible range of electronic circuits. The next special case with some additions has numerous practical applications. It doesn't need separate stable local oscillator.

[image]

This principle is used to detect the frequency change or phase shift that phenomena X causes to light. The result can be extracted from the output voltage.

It works if the light source is stable enough. X has some time delay and when C is mixed with D in the photodiode beam D must resemble enough what B was before that delay. Mathematicians call the stability "coherence" and have defined measures for it. I skip them.

The simplest application of the principle is distance interferometer. X is only a walk to a reflecting mirror or prism and back.  If one wants to move the mirror or prism a certain distance he counts how many voltage minimums and maximums occur in the output voltage when the movement happens. They occur at every quarter of the wavelength.

Another interesting thing is to measure the speed of the reflecting mirror or prism. It can be used to detect how much a machine vibrate or to listen what's said behind a window. The actual base idea is the same as in distance interferometer. The Doppler frequency just occurs as the AC component of the output voltage.

Unfortunately there's an ambiquity. We cannot easily decide if certain Doppler frequency is caused by growing or diminishing delay in X. One possible solution is to use literally complex (based on complex number signal vector math) 2 channel mixing; the other has 90 degrees phase shifted reference D. Another way is to add some variable delay to the reference D:

[image]

X is growing or diminishing delay caused by walk forth and back to a moving reflector. The sign of the Doppler shift is lost in mixing. Without any math you should understand that the direction can be reasoned by checking what increasing the voltage controlled delay causes. Increasing delay means the same as the lower beam path length grows. If the Doppler frequency decreases, the reflector is also moving further away.

The voltage controlled delay is a litium niobate crystal which has varying DC voltage between its surfaces. As well it can be mechanically vibrating mirror which makes the lower beam path in turns longer and shorter.

Third commonly used application is optical gyro. If a winding made of optical fiber is rotated around its axis the delay caused to the light in fiber depends on the rotation speed and is the rotation direction the same or opposite with the light in the fiber. (the reasons of the caused delay difference are complex, I skip them)

Fiber optic gyro applies also varying reference delay in the lower beam path. There's a control circuit which tries to keep the detector output constant:

[image]

This has numerous weaknesses which force to make the actual device more complex:

- the fiber winding must be long (=miles) if for ex. slow tilting of an aeroplane is wanted to be noticed. This means so long delay (tens of microseconds) that the laser stability is not so sure and the compensating voltage controlled delay is impossible. It's solved by rotating both beams through the same fiber to opposite directions.
- Noise and aging of the photodiode makes keeping the Uout constant a game of guessing. It's much easier to let the beam diverge from the combiner to bigger area where an interference pattern is formed. Having more photodiodes in that area or even a CCD camera one can keep the interference pattern constant which is much more reliable than trying to keep Uout certain value or in maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine two lights together, you add their intensities. Combined intensity is \$E_\text{s} + E_{\text{LO}}\$ and its power is proportional to square of it $$(E_\text{s} + E_{\text{LO}})^2 = E_\text{s}^2 + 2E_\text{S} E_{\text{LO}} + E_{\text{LO}}^2.$$

The \$2E_\text{S} E_{\text{LO}}\$ is important because multiplying sine-waves results in adding/subtracting frequencies $$\cos(a) \cdot \cos(b) = \dfrac{1}{2} \cos(a + b) + \dfrac{1}{2} \cos(a - b).$$

Electric output of detector depends on power of the optical signal, so there will be signal at frequency \$f_{\text{sig}}-f_{\text{local}}\$. If these are close together, resulting frequency will be small enough to be usable in circuit.

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't address the question. I'm specifically interested in the hardware involved.

Comment: Heterodyning means converting a signal to a lower (or higher) frequency by multiplying it with signal from local oscillator. In radio circuits (the Wiki article you linked), the multiplying happens in a device called mixer. In optics, it is enough to add the lights and multiplication happens as result of adding amplitudes but measuring power. Hardware involved can be as simple as two beams of light shining on the same photodiode (probably merged using some lens).

Comment: @JiříMaier He is asking how you actually shift the reference relative to the signal (e.g. AOM, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Any method that provides a non-linearity or modulation function of the incoming optical signal by another (usually RF signal) can produce mixing products (heterodyne).

Mixing can occur between two optical signals at the receiver diode to produce the difference signal, however although this can be used to provide synchronous optical detection it is not of use in an interferometer as the modulated optical signal is never in existence.

This example uses an Acoustic Optical Modulator to provide the heterodyning. ([Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator)

[image: Digitally Enhanced Heterodyne Interferometry]

[Techbriefs - Heterodyne Interferometry](https://www.techbriefs.com/component/content/article/tb/supplements/ptb/briefs/10332)

Any method that provides a non-linearity or modulation function of the incoming optical signal can produce mixing products (heterodyne).

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions here that need some explainations to piece apart. I'm not actually totally sure what your are asking or trying to do (using heterodyning in optics isn't really used for communications, but it's used in optical metrology for things like autocorrelators or specific types of long wave infrared spectrometers) so here are some points:

1. How do you shift the wavelength of light to get the sum or difference of the light's optical frequency (i.e., $$c/\lambda$$)? To do that you need to combine the light in a non-linear crystal like BPO. But that's not what you are looking for, I think.
2. In interferometry, you "beat" the two signals together by combining them both together on a detector, then varying the phase of one of the two inputs. You can vary the phase using an electo-optical (EO) phase shifter or by using a Michelson interferometer and slowly moving a mirror that delays one of the two light paths. Look up "Fourier transform infrared spectrometers" (FTIR) for some diagrams of an interferometer that uses a type of heterodyning to measure light frequency relative to a reference.
3. In telecommunications, it's more common to use another method of separating channels, like gratings. There they measure the signal as a function of frequency but don't use heterodyning.

Comment: My post specifically says heterodyne interferometry — I never even mentioned communication.

Comment: Got it, for some reason I thought it was some signal you were trying to piece out. In that case you just interfere the two onto any detector. The beat frequency will be the difference. Don't really need much hardware. Is it a free space or fiber application?

Comment: Free space. Exactly the type of metrology application you alluded to. The ‘thing’ that is vibrating is vibrating with a frequency of 1 MHz.

Comment: got it - i'll write up a different answer. I'm an optical engineer,  so this is a cool question to see on electronics SE for me! EDIT - ah, you're making a laser doppler vibrometer, that helps too

Comment: great, thanks! Since you’re going to take the time to write up an answer, I’ll give some additional background information. It’s a laser Doppler vibrometer application, measuring an object/surface that is vibrating at a frequency of 1 MHz. I’ve just started learning this stuff, and I was aware that acousto-optic modulators were used in LDVs, but I had no idea that they were used for *this* purpose (as described in my main question). […]

Comment: […] So the purpose of this question was to combine the theoretical explanation I had read with the practical electronics, so that I could gain a more comprehensive and practical understanding of how this works (also for the case of actually building one). Feel free to ask any questions.